# NSWindow orderOut -- is there a way to wait for the window to close?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

In my program, I have a window that the user positions on-screen over the part that he wants to take a picture of.

Then, when he clicks the button to take a picture, my program `orderOut`'s the window, takes a screenshot, and shows the window again, now with a screenshot in it.

The problem is, `orderOut` doesn't seem to close the window immediately. So when I take the screenshot, it usually takes a screenshot of the window itself (which should've been closed), which obviously is not what I want.

I've been able to side-step the problem by calling `sleep(1)` after calling `orderOut`, but surely there is a better way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, it's not a hack. The orderOut happens, I assume, as fast as it can given the refresh rate of the screen, which is probably considerably slower than executing one line of code.  An alternate approach might be to implement the delegate method, windowDidResignMain: which is called when the window closes, and call your picture taking method in there.  That might give it enough time to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

According the the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIBHEIE). The window does an animation when you call orderOut. Therefore, you can either remove the orderOut animation by setting the animation behavior to none :

```
[myWindow setAnimationBehavior:NSWindowAnimationBehaviorNone]
```

or use the NSObject method **performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:** to perform your screen shot operation after a certain amount of time x. Assuming the NSWindow orderOut animation uses the default duration, the delay would be 0.2f. Otherwise, you can make some tests to check what is the suitable value in your case.

Comment: Just tried disabling the animation, and it still doesn't work. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is just another way of doing my `sleep` hack..